# Django on mac Catalina

Tags: python, django, macos

When I run `python manage.py migrate`

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'safetobeme'
```

And what's bizarre is that when I search for "safetebeme" on google I get nothing.

I'm on Mac Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> python3 manage.py migration.

Sometimes it can work well.

Or check whether your environment is right.